# Preventing a textbox from capturing the MouseWheel event

Tags: vb.net, mousewheel

I have a `textbox` and when I scroll down my form with the mouse wheel and hit the textbox with the mouse, it stops scrolling.

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: A mouse pointer does not commonly change a text editor, surely you can phrase that better?  Using a Label instead of TextBox would be the most obvious way to avoid confusing the dickens out of your user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, If I understand you correctly, what you are searching is to keep mouse wheeling while passing on your TextBox. Is that correct ?

There is, I think, a way to achieve that. This code however has not been tested, so keep me informed if it worked.

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponents()
    'Other inits here
    AddHandler TextBox1.MouseWheel, AddressOf TBMouseWheel
End Sub

Private Sub TBMouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Me.OnMouseWheel(e)
End Sub
```

This way, when your textbox captures a MouseWheel event, it is passed on the form, which will handle it (I think). Sorry I don't have the opportunity to test it right now, but I believe this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the visual part, change the property "Cursor" of the textbox to "Arrow"

[image]

Comment: Nope, is the avoid of focus what i need

Comment: I don't think that focus normally changed when you hover the mouse over a control.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a `TextBox` to be focused, you have a few solutions

1. Set the `ReadOnly` property to True

Nobody will be able to enter text in your `TextBox`, exept if you do it programatically. However, it will still be possible to click on it and if clicked you will see the blinking cursor (don't know the name in English). When the mover hovers it it will turn into a cursor.

*This means this option allows the focus on the control, but it will not be possible to enter data.*

2. Set the `Enabled` property to False

Again, it will not be possible to enter any data. Also, it will not be possible to click on it and the cursor will not change if you hover it.

*This means this option disallows the focus on the control.*

3. Put a `Label` instead

If nobody will ever be able to insert data in your `TextBox`, maybe it is better to put a `Label` there. If you choose option 1 or 2, it is because at some point you might allow user to change the text inside. But if it will only be modified by the program, `Label` is good enough.

*Focus is never allowed on Labels.*

Comment: Thx for the answer. But my problem is when my cursor touch the textbox, my wheel of mouse stop. The property enabled=false  It works, but I can not allow this solution.